# How to check for camelCase in javascript

Tags: javascript, camelcasing

I need to add custom validation for a Name field. The name however needs to be camelCase. I need to add a check to see if its camelCase else throw an appropriate error message. I am not sure how to check for camelCase.
Any help will be much appreciated. Really stuck with this one.

Comment: do you have some examples and the wanted result?

Comment: seems like a job for regex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: who would you know it is not camel case?

Comment: You need the user to enter something in camelcase?  That's a bit unusual.

Comment: Does this help? [Camel Case on RegExr](https://regexr.com/2rilj)

Comment: This doesn't sound possible. How would you even be able to tell when the next word starts? You can probably just check for no space/special characters and check if the first letter is lowercase. Although I do agree with @Amy, that is pretty unusual and not very user friendly to force the user to enter the name in camelcase. What exactly is the use case here?

Answer (score 2):

Simply check for no whitespace, underscore, or other undesired symbols.

```js
// returns false if name includes whitespace, _, or -.
let validate = name => !name.match(/[\s_-]/g);

console.log(validate('yoBro')); // true
console.log(validate('yo bro')); // false
console.log(validate('yo_bro')); // false
console.log(validate('yo-bro')); // false
```

Comment: But it doesn't check for missing capitalization like `yobro` or Pascal casing like `YoBro`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very specific use case where we want to give some flexibility to our FE to be able to set arbitrary flags in the db through an internal service. I was looking for a regex for this and this is the best I found id the below

```
/^[a-z][A-Za-z]*$/
```

this ensures that

1 - it starts with a lower case

2 - includes (and ends on) only letters, be it upper or lower case

It doesn't avoid something like `iNpUt` or `iNPUT`- I guess something could be done to check that there aren't 2 consecutive upper case characters, but that sounds quote complicated...

You could also allow numbers from the second character onwards like so

```
^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```